# Prove that any odd number can be expressed as $4n+1$ or $4n+3$

Tags: proof-writing

Prove that any odd number can be expressed as $$4n+1$$ or $$4n+3$$
I can see that this is true, but I am not certain on how to make a formal proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: Every odd number can be written as $2k+1$. Now $k$ can be even ($k=2n$) or...

Comment: Much more than perfection!! :)

Comment: ... or $k$ can be odd? Can you explain a little further please?

Comment: Indeed, odd. That is $k=2n+1$. What do you get if you substitute these possibilities for $k$ in $2k+1$?

Comment: $2(2n+1)+1 = 4n+3$ and $2(2n)+1 = 4n+1$. sweet!